# Nodejs decrypt but some character gets corrupted while decrypting

Tags: node.js

I created a function to decrypt but some character gets corrupted while decrypting. What could this problem be caused by?

{"text":"aynısı"}

UYtydz+463tLN2HDon9c+Q/pYeL2JDcJEXAsKsGIIgY=

{"text":"aynıs��"}

```
const encryptionType = 'aes-256-cbc';
const encryptionEncoding = 'base64';
const encryptionEncodingHex = 'hex';
const bufferEncryption = 'utf-8';

const decryptJwt = (cipherText) => {
  const buff = Buffer.from(cipherText, encryptionEncoding);
  const KEY = Buffer.from(SECRET, bufferEncryption);
  const IV = Buffer.alloc(16);

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(encryptionType, KEY, IV);
  const deciphered = decipher.update(buff).toString(bufferEncryption) + decipher.final().toString(bufferEncryption);

  return deciphered;
};
```

Comment: Does it also happen when you put `bufferEncryption` to `utf8` instead? Not sure if that will make a difference, but you'll never know if you don't try :)

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Adriaan where did he add answer to the question body ?

Comment: @Paul-Marie see [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74688718/revisions), I've rolled back that edit already.

Comment: Okay so he answered his question by himself ? so why didn't you post it as an anwser for futur reader and mark it as closed ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed:

```
let decrypted = decipher.update(buff, 'hex', 'utf8');

// Getting decrypted data
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
```